# Why did Shannon break up with Jung?

Tags: plot-explanation, kims-convenience

In the finale of *Kim's Convenience* (S05E13), Shannon breaking up with Jung comes out of nowhere. Afterwards, they go up for dinner like nothing has happened.

Why did she break up with him?

Comment: I recall it being due to Jung saying that he'd propose marriage to Shannon on the Amazing Race in order to get on the show, but it would just be for the show - Jung had no real ambitions to marry Shannon otherwise and was content with just the boyfriend/girlfriend life, and Shannon wanted more. This doesn't mean they hate each other, just it was time for Shannon to move on and find a relationship with someone who wanted marriage because of her, not for convenience.

Comment: @user25730 you should turn that into an answer, maybe with some quotes for reference

Comment: That's not how I remember it. Initially, he wanted only to fake it. But when she considered it seriously, he was happy to consider it as well. My expectation was that they are going to work it out. The break up came out of no where.

Answer (score 2):

Nicole Power, who played Shannon, was given a spinoff show called [Strays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strays_(TV_series)).  At this point on the show Simu Liu was on track to be a much bigger star, and presumably would not appear in a small spinoff show.  The writers probably needed a quick way to break them up.  The dinner just seemed like bad editing or a continuity error.

Comment: This may have been the writers' motivation. But how was the break up explained in terms of a plot?

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  I guess I have no idea.  The whole last season was garbage, anyways.